# Apple Pay integration for Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, applepay, applepayjs

I want to integrate Apple Pay to NetSuite payment profile,
User will purchase some product from my web store and pay from Apple Pay.

Anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consume the services from Apple pay. In netsuite you will need Restlet to make the synch possible. I think you are the first timer with Netsuite, If you are doing this for the first time you will need expert guidance for making the sync possible.